# OSError: libDTKLPR5.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: operating-system, ctypes, loadlibrary, ubuntu-22.04, python-3.11

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ni8lN.jpg)trying to use `cdll.LoadLibrary` function in Python 3.11.0 in Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS 64-bit.

Below error occured. If you have faced this kind of issue please help.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/*****/Desktop/python-camera-app-latest/radius-camera-app/main.py", line 10, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/*****/Desktop/python-camera-app-latest/radius-camera-app/main.py", line 5, in main
    handler = DTKVideoStreamHandler()
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/*****/Desktop/python-camera-app-latest/radius-camera-app/Services/Implements/DTKVideoStreamHandler.py", line 28, in _init_
    self.__DTKLPR = cdll.LoadLibrary(DTKLPR5Lib)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/ctypes/_init_.py", line 454, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/ctypes/_init.py", line 376, in __init_
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
OSError: libDTKLPR5.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or director
```

Thanks in advance...

In windows 10 64-bit. There is some kind of solution with using

```
        os.add_dll_directory(full_path)
```

before calling

```
        self.__DTKLPR = cdll.LoadLibrary(DTKLPR5Lib)
```

but this solution is not working in Ubuntu. Because `add_dll_directory` is supposed to only windows. (Based on information in its documentation)

Comment: Please don't post images of text or errors.  Post the actual text.

Comment: @MarkTolonen Okay, sure. Updating